# exec function in Python3 with dataframe

Tags: python, pyspark

I am not able to make changes to an existing dataframe by calling the exec function dynamically.

```
>>>>df.columns
["col1","col2"]
>>>>change = "df.withColumnRenamed('col2', 'column2')"
>>>>exec("df =" + change)
```

Current Output

```
>>>>df.columns
["col1","col2"]
```

Expected Output

```
>>>>df.columns
["col1","column2"]
```

The execution runs without any issues. But the column does not get renamed.I have tried several changes, but to no avail

Comment: Have you tried just inspecting the dataframe returned by `df.withColumnRenamed('col2', 'column2')`? What are its column names?

Comment: Yes,I see the output as unchanged

Comment: The [pyspark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.withColumnRenamed) for the withColumnRenamed method states: "This is a no-op if schema doesn’t contain the given column name." Are you sure you haven't made a typo in the column name, perhaps...?

Comment: Let me provide another code -